# Passing arguments to jar in batch

Tags: java, batch-file

I have a batch file which I intend to be able to drag a jar file onto then write arguments for it into the console. The current .bat code is as follows:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET "finish="
SET "args="
SET /p args="Arguments: "
java -jar %1% "%args%"
SET /p finish="Exiting (Enter to exit)..."
```

However, when I run it, it seems to put "%args%" as part of the same string as %1%, giving the error: `Error: Unable to access jarfile C:Users\... .jarargs`. Is there a way to seperate the two?

Comment: try ``java -jar "%1" "%args"``

Comment: That seems to pass "args" as a string as the argument but `java -jar "%1" "%args"` does exactly what I wanted - thankyou!

Comment: Where's the difference to what i wrote?

Comment: Sorry, mistyped: `java -jar "%1" "%args%"`

Comment: I'd go for `java -jar "%~1" "%args%"`...

Comment: What is the difference between the two?